# Segmentation fault in skip list

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am implementing a skip list. The insertion function works fine and is able to print the list. But now I am trying to implement the "find" function and in this function I am getting a segmentation fault at the condition of while loop . When I debug the code , it works fine for all iterations except the last one. In the last iteration during condition check to enter in while loop it shows segmentation fault at this line precisely

**while(x->rgt->key < searchKey)**

I am not able to understand the reason because when I do handrun of the code everything seems fine. Please have a look and tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Also find function works fine if i search 1 and 2 but at 3 and 4 the fault occurs.

```
class SkipList
{

private:

         struct node{

         int key;
         int data;
         int level;
         struct node* rgt = nullptr;
         struct node* dwn = nullptr ;

         node(int k, int value, int l):
         key(k), data(value), level(l)
            {}

        };


        //generates the ndde level in tha range [1,maxLevel).
        int randomLevel() const;

        //returns a set of pointers to the location at each node where new links are to be created
        std::vector<node*> update(int searchKey) const ;

        //creates a new node and returns a pointer to it
        static node* makeNode(int key, int val, int level);

        // Returns the first node for which node->key < searchKey is false
        node* lower_bound(int searchKey) const;

        const float probability;
        const int maxLevel;


        // head and tail vectors
        vector<node*> head;
        vector<node*> nil;


public:

        SkipList();
      // ~SkipList();
        void insert(int searchKey, int val);

        void find(int searchKey) const;

        void erase(int searchKey);

        void print() const;

 };



SkipList::SkipList() :
probability(0.5), maxLevel(4)
{

head.resize(maxLevel, nullptr);
nil.resize(maxLevel,nullptr);

int headkey = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
int nilkey  = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

   for(int i = 0; i < maxLevel ;i++)
   {

    head[i] = new node(headkey,0,maxLevel-1);
    nil[i] = new node(nilkey,0,maxLevel-1);

       if(i>0)
       {
         head[i]->dwn = head[i-1];
         nil[i] ->dwn = nil[i-1];
       }

       head[i]->rgt = nil[i];
 }


}


void SkipList::find(int searchKey) const
 {
 node* x = head[maxLevel-1];

for(int i = maxLevel-1 ; i>= 0 ;i--)
{
  while(x->rgt->key < searchKey)
  {
    x = x->rgt;
  }

   if(i != 0){x = x->dwn;}

 }

if ((x->rgt->key == searchKey))
   cout<<"Found"<<endl;
}


void SkipList::insert(int searchKey, int val)
{
vector <node*> preds  = update(searchKey);
node* temp;

const int newLevel = randomLevel();



for(int i = 0; i< newLevel; i++)
{
 node* ptr = makeNode(searchKey,val, newLevel-1);

 temp = preds[i]->rgt;
 preds[i]->rgt = ptr;
 ptr->rgt = temp;

 }

}





void SkipList::print() const
{
node *ptr = head[0]->rgt;

while(ptr->rgt != nullptr)
{

 cout<<"Key: "<<ptr->key<<"  Data: "<<ptr->data<<"  Level: "<<ptr->level<<endl;
 ptr = ptr->rgt;
}



}



int SkipList::randomLevel() const
{
int v = 1;
while (((double)std::rand() / RAND_MAX) < probability &&
    v < maxLevel)
{
    v++;
}
return v;
}


SkipList::node* SkipList::makeNode(int key, int value, int level)
{

return new node(key, value, level);
}



std::vector<SkipList::node*>SkipList::update(int searchKey) const
{

 int level = head[0]->level;

 std::vector<node*> result(level,nullptr);

 node* x ;

 for(unsigned int i = level;i-- >0;)
 {
 x = head[i];
 while(x->rgt->key < searchKey)
 {
   x = x->rgt;
 }
  result[i]= x;

}

return result;

}




int main()
{

SkipList s;
int x,y;

for(int i = 1;i< 5;i++)
{

s.insert(i,i);

}
s.print();
cout<<endl;
s.find(3);




return 0;

}
```

Comment: First guess: `node* x = head[maxLevel-1]` should be `node* x = head[maxLevel]`

Comment: But internally the vector is stored as 0.....maxLevel-1 ?? This is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple debug shows this in this loop:

```
while(x->rgt->key < searchKey)
{
    x = x->rgt;
}
```

The value of `x` becomes `NULL`.

I am guessing that this is a case where you try to add an element at the end of the list.

If so, then you should come up with a different solution for this case.

For example:

```
while(x->rgt && x->rgt->key < searchKey)
{
    x = x->rgt;
}
if (x->rgt)
{
   // Use your original code
}
else
{
    // Handle this special case
}
```

Comment: I don't think your edit will work. I mean when `x` becomes `NULL`, you will invoke UB by attempting to dereference it, right?

Comment: @gsamaras: `x` will not become `NULL` here (unless it is `NULL` to begin with, but if I understand correctly, then the assumption in this function is that the initial value of `x` is a valid memory address).

Comment: doesnt print at all

Comment: @AkankshaDixit: I gave you an explanation to what the problem is, not a solution!!! In case you haven't noticed, there are two stubs in the code which I have left for you to complete. This is not a free-of-charge coding service in case you missed that part!!!!!

Comment: in this case i think the above edit will not do any good beacuse as you can see that the last node in each level is a value whose key will be higher than any int value that I try to insert. that i have ensured through this statement:int nilkey  = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

Comment: @goodvibration relax man the first comment was in response to your first comment which was eventually edited.

Comment: @AkankshaDixit: There was no fix-suggestion in my original answer (only the part until "`x` becomes `NULL`"), which makes your "doesnt print at all" comment totally out of context. With regards to the "edit above" - I merely pointed out the problem in your `while` loop, while speculating your intentions in that loop. Whether or not this speculation was correct, the problem that I pointed out remains the one that you should deal with. How you do it is up to you, but you most certainly need to ensure that `x->rgt` is not `NULL` (using `x->rgt &&` at the beginning of the loop condition).

Comment: see I am trying to say one thing here. even if the x pointer is at the second last node after which is the NIL node , the key of each NIL node is always greater than an possible int value. So the condition for while will never result in nullptr because the x pointer will not move forward when it is on second last node after which I have my NIL node. so why do you think x will reach NULL?

Comment: @AkankshaDixit: I don't "think `x` will reach `NULL`". I know it will, because I ran your code in the debugger and saw it in my own eyes!